# running shell script using c program

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts, c

I wrote a script to hide user input during runtime it works as a simple script but i want to integrate into c program but gives following errors:

```
warning: missing whitespace after macro name 

error: expected ')' before 'Password'
```

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Here's the c program:

```
#include"header.h"
#define SHELLSCRIPT"\
#bin/bash\n\
printf"Password Please:"\n\

stty -echo\n\

read pass\n\

stty echo\n\

printf'\n'\n\

sleep"2"\n\

echo "$pass"\n\

"

int main()

{

puts("Will execute sh with following script:");

puts("SHELLSCRIPT");

puts("Starting now");

system(SHELLSCRIPT);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a programming question and is more appropriate for http://stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: Also, your first line "#bin/bash\n\" is missing "!", i.e. "#!bin/bash\n\". That might be a source of problems. I have never tried what you are doing, but you might also have to explicitely call bash in the system command "/bin/bash script.sh".

Comment: Why do you even bother to write a C program if you end up running an Sh script anyway? That is not to say you can't change the `echo` state of the terminal in plain C. Alternatively you could use one of the existing programs that safely ask the user for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
// Compile with:
// gcc     c-shellscript.c   -o c-shellscript

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
printf 'Password Please:';\n\
stty -echo;\n\
read pass;\n\
stty echo;\n\
printf '\\n';\n\
sleep 2;\n\
echo $pass;"

int main()

{

  puts("Will execute sh with following script:");

  puts("---------");
  puts(SHELLSCRIPT);
  puts("---------");

  puts("Starting now");

  system(SHELLSCRIPT);

  return 0;

}
```

However, **I don't think it is good practice to do things this way**.
It is also much much easier to create a separate shellscript file and just call that instead, even if you generate the shellscript file from within your code.

Have a look at these for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736210/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-c-in-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/646260/105315
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245600/using-a-single-system-call-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-c

Comment: one advantage of using c to launch a script is that you can then set the c program as executable but not readable (the script still needs to be readable to be executed, but can be "hidden" somewhere else)